# How to fix ReferenceError: error is not defined in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, visual-studio-code, mern

**ReferenceError: error is not defined**

Getting issue when I'm running a route in the Postman then I get this error

```
exports.createContact = (req, res, fields) => {

const {name, email, message} = fields;

if (!name, !email, !message) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(404).json({
        error: "Please fill all the details",
        
    })
    
}

let contact = new Contact(fields)

contact.save((err, contact) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(200).json({
            error: "Failed to create contact"
        })
    }
    res.json(contact)
})
```

}

Specially the error on this line

```
   console.log(err);
```

Comment: Don't you mean the `console.log(error);` one? Besides, where is `error` even defined?

Comment: `if (!name, !email, !message) {` makes no sense.

Comment: None of this code makes much sense. Back to the drawing board :)

Comment: Look at line 6. `error` is not defined in the current scope. Unless `error` is defined globally, it does not exist.

Comment: Well the console.log(error) is show the error of return res.status(404).json({
        error: "Please fill all the details", in the console of vsCode